# Need to change the model name with another model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am ruby on rails guys.

Let me explain what I need.

I have one model, I have to changed the name of this model with different name.
Let me know What are things we need to changed.
Means need to change controller name, view , routes .

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some similar questions on Stackoverflow. Two possible options:

1. Rails doesn't have a built in method to do this in one step, but you can do DB migrations + find-replace in a text editor. See: [How to re-name a ActiveRecord Model which can automatically change the table name in DB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826879/how-to-re-name-a-activerecord-model-which-can-automatically-change-the-table-nam)
2. You can use a Ruby on Rails IDE with some refactoring tools / techniques to help you out. See: [Change model name in rails easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784701/change-model-name-in-rails-easily), http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/